# Devise role based routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, routes, cancan

I have an app with multiple users.  Each user as a theoretical role (user, client, etc).  I've designed a view/controller for each user type.

I want to be able to login each type of user do a different root url and lock them to it.

Originally I was going to add a column to Users in Devise called role and so I can differentiate the users.  The problem I'm having is how to say in routes.rb if current_user.role == "client" root :to => 'controller#index'

Once they are logged in to the page I also want to keep them from being able to visit any of my other paths ie: domain.com/calls domain.com/units

I've been looking into cancan to run alongside Devise but I'm not sure if this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling it in routes, why not handle it in ApplicationController?

```
#application_controller.rb
before_filter :direct_to

def direct_to
  if current_user.role == "client"
    redirect_to client_controller_path
  # etc
end
```

Comment: That's a good idea and would work.  What would be the best way to lock them to that page and keep them from possibly going to calls_path or units_path?

Comment: If you're doing it in the application controller on every call, I don't think it's going to be a problem

Comment: I tried the above code and it ends up in a redirect loop. Any thoughts as to why?  I put it in the application controller and it redirects to the path I chose but displays a blank page with a web request redirect loop.