# Routing for Multiple User Roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user model that differentiates into 6 roles, and I am defining different variables and directing them to different view files (similar format, but different tables of information), but within the same controller action, because they all have similar pages "overview", "profile", "messages", etc.

Now the controller is really messy, and has multiple if/else statements. I believe I should be  changing the routes so that each user has its own controller, eliminating the use of the if/else monstrosity that currently invades the controller.

```
def index
  if current_user.admin?
    ....
  end
  if current_user.moderator?
   ....
  end
end
```

Question: How do I perform the routing such that url will be 
www.website.com/1/schedule, where 1 = current_user.id, while having different view files rendered from the different controllers?

I am thinking of doing a AdminController and a ModeratorController to handle this, but am not sure how to do the routing, or if indeed this is the best way to do it. Thanks for advice in advance!

Comment: Possible Duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053175/devise-role-based-routing  Hope it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it the wrong way , If you have similar pages for different role then I think you are accessing same model for handling different roles.

If this is the case then you  should use Gem like Cancan (authorization library for Ruby on Rails).

Comment: I am not authorising actions. I am going to different pages altogether. admins will render "admin_overview.html.slim"

Answer (score 0):

To address your second concern, I don't think this would be the best approach. Try this - move your logic away from multiple controllers, and keep the logic in the ApplicationController. I do not think that you should separate the different roles to controllers. Instead, look to your User model and put in a method that checks the privilege level for the different users. You could create methods in your User model that you could call in your controllers to see if the user is allowed access to the action. `before_action` would be recommended here.

If you decide to keep multiple controllers, I recommend a gem like Authority. Makes it much easier to keep track of different privileges, even across different controllers - I think routing is addressed as well: https://github.com/nathanl/authority

Comment: I currently have those query methods in the application controller, and thats how I'm testing for user roles in the index methods respectively. I just wonder if the if-else statements had a good way of being dissolved into a better structure.